Initialize a two-dimensional array with the values shown in the table below
Initialize a two-dimensional array with the values shown in the table below
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4
0   0   9   0   0   0   9   0   0   0
0   0   0   16  0   0   0   16  0   0
1   0   0   0   25  0   0   0   25  0
0   4   0   0   0   36  0   0   0   36
0   0   9   0   0   0   49  0   0   0
0   0   0   16  0   0   0   64  0   0
1   0   0   0   25  0   0   0   81  0
0   4   0   0   0   36  0   0   0  100

I tried doing a diagonal pattern but can't seem to execute this pattern.
This is my diagonal code.
In the above diagram, the diagonal pattern seems to start after every 3 intervals replaced with zeros


function matrixPattern() {
  let arr = [];
  let len = 10;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = i !== j ? 0 : (i + 1) * (j + 1)
    }
  }
  for (let i in arr) {
    let line = '';

    for (let j in arr[i]) {
      line += arr[i][j] + '\t';
    }

    console.log(line);
  }
}
matrixPattern()




Seems like you might need to use the modulus operator (%) to get your intervals...

You can use modulo logic to identify which diagonals get the non-zero values. Note that the distance between two diagonals is not 3 but 4: the first diagonal starts at (0, 0), and the one at its right at (4, 0)!
The non-zero values are squares of the minimum distance to the left or the top. So they are not the multiplication of two different values, but two the same values. The inner assignment could be:
arr[i][j] = (i - j) % 4 ? 0 : (Math.min(i, j) + 1) ** 2

So:


function matrixPattern() {
  let arr = [];
  let len = 10;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = (i - j) % 4 ? 0 : (Math.min(i, j) + 1) ** 2;
    }
  }
  return arr; 
}

const mat = matrixPattern();

for (const row of mat) console.log(...row);




Thank you so much this solves the problem. I don't know why I never thought of using the modulus approach.

Here is a solution that does not use modulo. It proceeds as follows.

Create an n x n array arr will all elements equal to zero.
Step down the diagonal by incrementing an index i from 0 to n-1.
Set diag = (i+1)**2 and arr[i][i] = diag
Set j = i+4
While j < n, set arr[i][j] and arr[j][i] to diag then j = j+4
If i = n-1 we are finished with the construction of arr; else set i = i+1 and repeat with Step 3.

In step 5, when setting arr[i][j] = diag, i can be thought of as a row index and j as a column index. When setting arr[j][i] = diag, j can be thought of as a row index and i as a column index.
Here is Ruby code to construct the array arr.
n = 10
# create an nxn array with all elements set to zero
arr = Array.new(n) { Array.new(n,0) }
# loop over i = 0 to n-1  
n.times do |i|
  diag = (i+1)**2
  arr[i][i] = diag
  # starting with j = i + 4, increment j by 4 while j < n
  j = i + 4
  while j < n
    arr[i][j] = diag
    arr[j][i] = diag 
    j = j + 4
  end
end

arr can be displayed as follows, confirming it is the desired array.
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4 
0   0   9   0   0   0   9   0   0   0
0   0   0  16   0   0   0  16   0   0
1   0   0   0  25   0   0   0  25   0
0   4   0   0   0  36   0   0   0  36
0   0   9   0   0   0  49   0   0   0
0   0   0  16   0   0   0  64   0   0
1   0   0   0  25   0   0   0  81   0
0   4   0   0   0  36   0   0   0 100

